# Need to extract a specific detail from a json

Tags: regex, amazon-redshift, regexp-substr

I have the following json which i'm looking to extract the specific string which come after location_code and between quotes **XXX123**

> {"location_code":"**XXX123**","location_uuid":"XXX-XXX-XXAA-4444-ASDFSDAF44","hotstamp":"1111","card_format":"ABC","accesses":[{"partition_name":"SSSSuljiro","SSSSS":"3","access_levels":["ASDASDASDA"],"location_code":"XXX123"}]}

Would greatly appreciate any help with this!!
I'm using redshift and tried several attempts with regexp_substr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
(?<="location_code":")\w+
```

but since you want to parse a json object, there could be better/easier ways to do so.

Comment: If you are using `\w` you don't need to add `\d` too.

Comment: Thanks @UnbearableLightness changed it.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you could use `json_extract_path_text`:

```
select json_extract_path_text(
  json_column, -- your json
  'location_code', -- json key to extract data from
  true -- return null if input is invalid json
);
```

Make sure that your string is actually valid `JSON` format.

Comment: Thanks, Kamil, I'm new at SO, and seems as I can only rate one person, even though your suggestion also works perfectly - much appreciated!